# asymptotics of the Fourier transform of Daubechies wavelet

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-series

I want to evaluate the series

\begin{equation}
S(\alpha,\omega)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{|\Psi(2k\pi-\omega)|^2}{|2k\pi-\omega|^\alpha}
\end{equation}
where $0\le\omega<2\pi$, $0<\alpha<1$ and $\Psi(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of the Daubechies wavelet.

From the basics of Daubechies wavelet, we know $\Psi(\omega)$ decays very fast thus the above series converges. But without a closed-form expression for $\Psi(\omega)$, this series is hard to evaluate numerically to a tolenrated precision, in my opinon. I guess by calculating the first $M$ terms of the series and using an asymptotics for the remaining would work, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
S(\alpha,\lambda)=\sum_{k=-M}^{M}\frac{|\Psi(2k\pi-\omega)|^2}{|2k\pi-\omega|^\alpha} + 2\sum_{k=M+1}^{\infty}\frac{|\Psi(2k\pi-\omega)|^2}{|2k\pi-\omega|^\alpha}
\end{equation}

but it requires an asymptotic for the second term of the right side of the equation, or more specifically, an asymptotic for $\Psi(\omega)$.

Is there an asymptotic for $\Psi(\omega)$, or is there a better  way to evaluate the series?

Thank you for your answer